# How to stop certain component from loading when i visit another component

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am working on a Mern-stack Application, and I want some info inside my App.js to not show when I visit Blog and other components.

Example:
anytime I visit the Blog page, I don't' want my full image slider and other components that I have in my App.js to display, rather I want the contents of that particular component that I visited to display only.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should consider navigation based on URL in your app. You can display specific view basing on URL match.

For example, at the root URL `/` you display your full image slider and other home page stuff, and when the URL is `/blog` you display your Blog component.

One really nice and intuitive way to do it in react is using [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/philosophy).